# Starting with ListFrament

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I've been working on my first app for android. I know exactly what I want, but don't know how to develop it. I already knows that I've to use `ListFragment`. So, I've search the internet for tutorials & guides. But, I don't understand it 100%.
I've also read the Android Developer Guide.

So, I ask you guys to help my with my first app.
I don't ask for large codes. Just a simple starter code for me to understand `ListFragment`.
Also, links to good tutorials are allowed.

Thanks!

PS: I want my `ListFragment` data from a XML file

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to the FAQ here: http://stackoverflow.com/faq to understand why your post isn't a good fit for this site. There are plenty of tutorials on ListFragments out there. Find one, follow one, and when you get stuck and a have a specific question, come back here and post it -- after confirming that it isn't one of the 200,000+ questions that has already been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all welcome to the Android community.

Creating your first app with fragments is a very big first step. You might want to start with the "Hello world" tutorial and try to create all the basic layouts first.

Make sure you read the [App fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fundamentals.html) ([especially about activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)) from the official Android developers site, this website is gold for you right now.

If you really want to start with fragments make sure you have read [the fragment section](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Now for really cool examples, the best thing to do actually is install Eclipse and install everything else required to start developing your first application.

As explained [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html)

Now Eclipse with the Android plugin has a really cool wizard which actually creates an example with list and detail fragments!

[image]

Comment: I already read the basic stuff. And I also read the Fragment Section. But, what should be nice is a basic little script that I can understand. Just a example from someone that isn't to difficult is enough.

Comment: Like I said Eclipse + ADT plugin has an fragment activity example which is very easy to understand if you combine this with other helpful tutorials. You really shouldn't ask for example scripts here, this is not what SO is about. Good luck!

Comment: The Activity example is called MasterDetailFlow as shown in this screenshot: http://imgur.com/gaAcWS7

Comment: Okay! But, do you know other sites where I can ask questions. And, MasterDetailFlow is not standing in the list by me.

Comment: Yes I do, but you are not asking a question which can be solved  by a simple answer, you are asking for example code / script or snippets.  So like I said these are only to be found in tutorials or examples like @Emil Adz has posted.

Comment: Okay, than I will learn the Android Guide extra good and search for good tutorials.